# fsevents command line

Tags: objective-c, macos, fsevents

I have written an objective-c class for watching a particular folder using FSEventStreamCreate(). This class work as expected when I am using it in GUI based application.

Now I am trying to write a commandline application using this class. The project fails to link :(

following is the error message

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_FSEventStreamCreate", referenced from:
>         -[MyFSWatcher initializeEventStream] in MyFSWatcher.o
>     "_FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
>         -[MyFSWatcher initializeEventStream] in MyFSWatcher.o
>     "_FSEventStreamStart", referenced from:
>         -[MyFSWatcher initializeEventStream] in MyFSWatcher.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

I am guessing I am missing some linker flags. Can someone please point that out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FSEvents API is part of CoreServices, so you'll need to link against that.

If you're compiling from the commandline, use:

`clang -framework CoreServices ...`

Comment: Yes thats right. I was just reading : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html